# Nlog GetCurrentClassLogger for Inheritance and callsite

Tags: .net, inheritance, nlog

I'm developing console .Net application and use Nlog for logging. I use *${callsite}* layout template for logging class name. I want to see in log file the name of inherited class when it called from parent

example:

```
using NLog;

namespace ConsoleApp17
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new MyClass2();
            a.Do1();
            a.Do2();
            a.Do3();
        }

        public class MyClass
        {
            protected virtual Logger Logger { get; } = null;

            public void Do1()
            {
                Logger.Info("Do1");
            }

            public virtual void Do2()
            {
                Logger.Info("Do2");
            }
        }

        public class MyClass2 : MyClass
        {
            protected override Logger Logger { get; } = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

            public override void Do2()
            {
                Logger.Info("Do22");
            }

            public void Do3()
            {
                Logger.Info("Do3");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

log is:

```
2017-05-18 18:22:02.7761|1|ConsoleApp17.Program+MyClass.Do1|INFO|Do1|

2017-05-18 18:22:02.8611|1|ConsoleApp17.Program+MyClass2.Do2|INFO|Do22|

2017-05-18 18:22:04.2831|1|ConsoleApp17.Program+MyClass2.Do3|INFO|Do3|
```

U see, that in lines 2 and 3 there is an inherited class name **MyClass2**, but in line 1 there is a parent class name **MyClass**.

How can i achieve writing to log an inherited class name when it's called from parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `${logger}` template instead of `${callsite}`.

When used together with `GetCurrentClassLogger()`, it will show the name of the object type that created the logger. In your case it will be `MyClass2`.